# package.json does not exist at /package.json

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda, google-ads-api

When I am trying to use webpack in order to build my project and use it on AWS Lambda, I am getting a lot of warnings related to **Critical dependency** of ./node_modules/**grpc**.
This issue happening once I `import {GoogleAdsApi} from 'google-ads-api';`
As I can understand this is related to dynamic importing, I might be wrong.
As a result, the bundled file is huge (above 4MB) and when zipping it and using it on the Lambda I am getting the following error when the Lambda is triggered: "package.json does not exist at /package.json"

*Typescript
*Node ver 12.x

**index.ts**

```
import {GoogleAdsApi} from 'google-ads-api';

export const handler = async (event: any): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    console.log('Start', event);
    // @ts-ignore
    const api = new GoogleAdsApi({client_id: 'id', client_secret: 'secret', developer_token: 'dToken'});
    return 'success';
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    throw e;
  }
};
```

```
Error: package.json does not exist at /package.json,
at Object.exports.find (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js:18:1),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:29:1),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:40079:30),
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:144:12),
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:35:27),
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/node_modules/grpc/index.js:27:14),
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2460:30)
```

**Webpack Warnings**
Webpack Warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js 29:38-55
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'memcpy' in   

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-ads-node/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js 28:8-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression


WARNING in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js 32:12-33
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression


WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 20:22-48
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js 17:20-67
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
`const path = require("path")
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
mode: "production",
entry: "./src/index.ts",
resolve: {
extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
},
output: {
libraryTarget: "commonjs",
path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
filename: "index.js",
},
target: "node",
module: {
rules: [
{
// Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
test: /.(ts|js)x?$/,
exclude: /node_modules/,
use: [
{
loader: "cache-loader",
options: {
cacheDirectory: path.resolve(".webpackCache"),
},
},
"babel-loader",
],
},
],
},
plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()],
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant or not, but i think you should use esbuild and add dependencies as dev. Shoould reduce your bundle size and should solve your problems